# Flags enum strange values

Tags: c#, enums, flags

```
[Flags]
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0x0000,
    Left = 0x0001,
    Right = 0x0002,
    Up = 0x0004,
    Down = 0x0008,
    Forward = 0x0016,
    Backward = 0x0032
}
```

Really confused, I'm using using this enum in an if statement like so:

```
if ((enumValues & Direction.Forward) == Direction.Forward)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

to check if it contains a flag inside the collection.

```
if ((enumValues & Direction.Right) == Direction.Forward)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Keeps running this `if ( Direction.Right )` code despite not containing the Right flag inside the collection, I've even debugged it with breaks and the value doesn't contain `Direction.Right` but it's still returning true and running the snippet.

Have I set up my enum wrong or am I querying the values wrong?

I don't use flags normally I just figured it would be a good use of them.

Comment: could you please show where `enumValues ` comes from?

Comment: Why don't you use more normal flags? Like Left=1 and Up=0?

Comment: `if ((enumValues & Direction.Right) == Direction.Forward)` - you've got two different values there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing how you have defined your enum:

```
None = 0x0000,
Left = 0x0001,
Right = 0x0002,
Up = 0x0004,
Down = 0x0008,
Forward = 0x0016,
Backward = 0x0032
```

You are confusing hexadecimal and decimal numbers.

In a `[Flags]` enum, the binary representation of the values of your enum should be something like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000
```

Which in decimal, are powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc

But the way you are writing the values start with `0x`, which denotes a hexadecimal value. So you are actually setting the values for the enum case as the *hex numbers* 1, 2, 4, 8 and 16.

You should remove those `0x`:

```
None = 0,
Left = 1,
Right = 2,
Up = 4,
Down = 8,
Forward = 16,
Backward = 32
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it sorted things :)

Comment: @ClownFishUK You can also write `Left = 1 << 0, Right = 1 << 1, Up = 1 << 2, Down = 1 << 3` and so on, which takes the hassle from making the calculations yourself and messing up. This works because << is the left bit shift operator which here moves the 1 bit the stated amounts of positions to the left. Writing `1 << 5` in my opinion also makes it clearer which bit a value like 32 alludes to.

Answer (score 1):

For hex you should define values like this:

```
Forward = 0x0010,
Backward = 0x0020
```

Or in decimal:

```
Forward = 16,
Backward = 32
```